# Minesweeper Object GUI

Tags: java, swing, object, minesweeper

I am trying to do a simple Minesweeper game using `JFrame`, however I am having troubles with the creation of objects. I am creating 96 buttons, some of which get the property of being wrong ("F") and right ("R"):

```
public class GUIBase extends JFrame {

private JButton button;
private JButton fButton;


public GUIBase() {
    super("Minesweeper");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    //Fields
    int position;
    for (int i = 0; i < 96; i++) {
        position = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
        if (position < 80) {
            button = new JButton("R");
            button.setToolTipText("Is this the correct one?");
            add(button);
        } else {
            fButton = new JButton("F");
            fButton.setToolTipText("Is this the correct one?");
            add(fButton);
        }           
    }
```

I then use `ActionListener` in order to check whether or not the button is correct. If the button is correct, it will get `.setEnabled(false)`, otherwise the game ends:

```
    //Action
    Action action = new Action();
    button.addActionListener(action);
    fButton.addActionListener(action);

}

private class Action implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Somethin");

        if (event.getSource() == button) {
            button.setEnabled(false);
        } else if (event.getSource() == fButton) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You lost!");
            System.exit(0);
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "An error ocurred");
            System.exit(0);
        }           
    }
}
```

Everything in the game turns out as planned, however only the last correct button ("R") and last wrong one ("F") are connected to the `ActionListener`. The rest of the buttons do not do anything when pressed.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Funny thing. You create 96 instances JButton objects, but you have a **single** field button within your class that will remember the exactly last JButton object you created. And you are surprised that your 95 other JButtons aren't happy? Besides: you rarely compare objects with ==, you use equals.

Comment: Side note: it seems that you are still on a beginner level with Java; your code indicates that there are still quite some basic concepts you haven't understood yet. But still you are trying to build a GUI application. That might be tempting; but seriously: consider learning how to dig holes **first**, before starting to build whole houses.

Comment: @Jägermeister  I do not how otherwise to create 96 instances with fields in a good and short-coded way. The reason I use == is because I follow an experienced tutor who uses the same methods. In what way is my code basic-level? Are there things I should change? If so, please answer the topic. Thanks.

Comment: Well, it seems that you not have heard of arrays. If you create 96 objects, and you want to later access them, maybe you have to put them into an array or list? But obviously, your problem is that tutor (tutorial?) you are following. Because it is simply wrong.

Comment: @Jägermeister I see. I am, as u sharply assumed, a beginner in the object-oriented part of Java. Nevertheless, I will try to solve it with lists. Thanks for your inestimable help.

Comment: And please keep in mind: the answer you got by now is only half of the situation. Your action listener requires a lot of rework, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you only have two variables (attributes of the class GUIBase, specifically), and your are assigning to it each time you create a new button. Hence, you only have a reference to the last buttons.

You need an array of buttons. Let's see:

```
public class GUIBase extends JFrame {
    public final int MAX_BUTTONS = 96;
    private JButton[] buttons;
// ...
}
```

The next step is to create the array itself at the beginning:

```
public GUIBase() {
    super("Minesweeper");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    this.buttons = new JButton[MAX_BUTTONS];


    //Fields
    int position;
    for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        position = (int) (Math.random() * 100);

        this.buttons[ i ] = new JButton("R");
        this.buttons[ i ].setToolTipText("Is this the correct one?");
        this.add(this.buttons[ i ]);

        Action action = new Action();
        this.buttons[ i ].addActionListener(action);
    }
}
```

You'll probably need more depth in arrays in order to completely understand the code. Basically, an array is a continuous collection of variables, which you can index by its position, from 0 to n-1, being n the number of positions.

Then you'll probably be able to fill the gaps yourself.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your inestimable help!

Answer (score 3):

One part of your problems is coming from your action listener.

Of course, one part is that your code **probably** needs a list/array to keep track of all created buttons; but at least right now, you can rework your code without using arrays/list:

```
private class Action implements ActionListener {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    System.out.println("Somethin");
    if (event.getSource() instanceofJButton) {
       JBUtton clickedButton = (JButton) event.getSource();
       String buttonText = clickedButton.getText();
       if (buttonText.equals("R") ...
       else if (buttonText.equals("F")
```

You see, the whole point here is: as of now, you just need to know what kind of button was created. And your ActionListener knows which button it was clicked on ...